# AngularJS hide div based on url/condition

Tags: angularjs, ng-show, ng-hide

This is my url - `charts/53d25d91959679701e362f25` and when I add `?widget=true` to that link `charts/53d25d91959679701e362f25?widget=true` I have to hide two particular divs in `charts/53d25d91959679701e362f25` page.

I've tried - `ng-if="location.path()"` but is not working for `?widget=true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `$location` service in `ng-if` directive

User `$location` to set some scope and tie `ng-if` to that scope variable.

```
if(angular.isDefined($location.search().widget)) {
     $scope.isHidden = true;
} 
else {
     $scope.isHidden = false;
}

ng-if="isHidden"
```

Comment: hi i've tried but it hides that div in all pages (not only in ?widget=true) page

Comment: All the pages? Do you use ngRoute? You can use a controller per page.

Comment: OK. A workaround would be try using different scope for each page like isHiddenPage1, isHiddenPage2 etc.

Comment: Actually the div is in include file (default.html), i need to hide main menu bar for that page. so there is no seperate controller/scope for that file.. let met try